# Python: OverflowError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer ECC-Crypto

Tags: python, json, encryption, cryptography, lib

this is my first post. Since I have tried the encryption and decryption library using ECC and I encountered the problem is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ecc_dec3.py", line 51, in <module>
    decryptedMsg = decrypt_ECC(encryptedMsgObj, privKey)
  File "ecc_dec3.py", line 22, in decrypt_ECC
    sharedECCKey = privKey * ciphertextPubKey
OverflowError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer
```

and this is my encryption code :

```
from tinyec import registry
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import hashlib, secrets, binascii
import json

def encrypt_AES_GCM(msg, secretKey):
    aesCipher = AES.new(secretKey, AES.MODE_GCM)
    ciphertext, authTag = aesCipher.encrypt_and_digest(msg)
    return (ciphertext, aesCipher.nonce, authTag)

def ecc_point_to_256_bit_key(point):
    sha = hashlib.sha256(int.to_bytes(point.x, 32, 'big'))
    sha.update(int.to_bytes(point.y, 32, 'big'))
    return sha.digest()

curve = registry.get_curve('brainpoolP256r1')

def encrypt_ECC(msg, pubKey):
    ciphertextPrivKey = secrets.randbelow(curve.field.n)
    sharedECCKey = ciphertextPrivKey * pubKey
    secretKey = ecc_point_to_256_bit_key(sharedECCKey)
    ciphertext, nonce, authTag = encrypt_AES_GCM(msg, secretKey)
    ciphertextPubKey = ciphertextPrivKey * curve.g
    return (ciphertext, nonce, authTag, ciphertextPubKey)

msg = b'{"led":[{"status":"ON"}]}'
print("Input message: ", msg)
privKey = secrets.randbelow(curve.field.n)
pubKey = privKey * curve.g

encryptedMsg = encrypt_ECC(msg, pubKey)
encryptedMsgObj = {
    'ciphertext': binascii.hexlify(encryptedMsg[0]),
    'nonce': binascii.hexlify(encryptedMsg[1]),
    'authTag': binascii.hexlify(encryptedMsg[2]),
    'ciphertextPubKey': hex(encryptedMsg[3].x) + hex(encryptedMsg[3].y % 2)[2:]
}
print("encrypted msg: \n", encryptedMsgObj)

'''saveJson = json.dumps(encryptedMsgObj)
with open('jsonencrypt.json','w') as encryptFile:
    encryptFile.write(saveJson)'''

#Save file to JSON
def python_dict_to_json_file(file_path):
    try:
        # Get a file object with write permission.
        file_object = open(file_path, 'w',encoding='utf-8')

        dict_object = dict(ciphertext = binascii.hexlify(encryptedMsg[0]).decode("ascii"),
                            nonce = binascii.hexlify(encryptedMsg[1]).decode("ascii"),
                            authTag = binascii.hexlify(encryptedMsg[2]).decode("ascii"),
                            ciphertextPubKey = hex(encryptedMsg[3].x) + hex(encryptedMsg[3].y % 2)[2:]
                          )

        # Save dict data into the JSON file.
        json.dump(dict_object, file_object)

        print("Save "+file_path + " created. ")    
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(file_path + " not found. ")    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    python_dict_to_json_file("./encryptData.json")
```

decrypt code:

```
from tinyec import registry
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import hashlib, secrets, binascii
import json
import sys

def decrypt_AES_GCM(ciphertext, nonce, authTag, secretKey):
    aesCipher = AES.new(secretKey, AES.MODE_GCM, nonce)
    plaintext = aesCipher.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, authTag)
    return plaintext

def encrypt_ECC(msg, pubKey):
    ciphertextPrivKey = secrets.randbelow(curve.field.n)
    sharedECCKey = ciphertextPrivKey * pubKey
    secretKey = ecc_point_to_256_bit_key(sharedECCKey)
    ciphertext, nonce, authTag = encrypt_AES_GCM(msg, secretKey)
    ciphertextPubKey = ciphertextPrivKey * curve.g
    return (ciphertext, nonce, authTag, ciphertextPubKey)

def decrypt_ECC(encryptedMsgObj, privKey):
    (ciphertext, nonce, authTag, ciphertextPubKey) = encryptedMsgObj
    sharedECCKey = privKey * ciphertextPubKey
    secretKey = ecc_point_to_256_bit_key(sharedECCKey)
    plaintext = decrypt_AES_GCM(ciphertext, nonce, authTag, secretKey)
    return plaintext

def ecc_point_to_256_bit_key(point):
    sha = hashlib.sha256(int.to_bytes(point.x, 32, 'big'))
    sha.update(int.to_bytes(point.y, 32, 'big'))
    return sha.digest()
curve = registry.get_curve('brainpoolP256r1')


with open('encryptData.json','r') as fh:
    dict = fh.read()
    dict_object = json.loads(dict)

encryptedMsgObj = {
    'ciphertext': dict_object['ciphertext'].encode("ascii"),
    'nonce': dict_object['nonce'].encode("ascii"),
    'authTag': dict_object['authTag'].encode("ascii"),
    'ciphertextPubKey': dict_object['ciphertextPubKey'].encode("ascii")
}
strhex = (bytearray(dict_object['ciphertextPubKey'],"utf-8"))
print("ciphertext :",dict_object['ciphertext'].encode("ascii"))
print('nonce: ',dict_object['nonce'].encode("ascii"))
print('authTag: ',dict_object['authTag'].encode("ascii"))
print('ciphertextPubKey :' , dict_object['ciphertextPubKey'])

privKey = secrets.randbelow(curve.field.n)
decryptedMsg = decrypt_ECC(encryptedMsgObj, privKey)
print("decrypted msg:", decryptedMsg)
```

and this is original code link : https://github.com/nakov/Practical-Cryptography-for-Developers-Book/blob/master/asymmetric-key-ciphers/ecc-encryption-decryption.md

I have the objective to receive the input message and encode it using ECC and save it as a json file. After that, decode it by reading from the encrypted json file. And save as plain text in plaintext.json

Comment: It looks to me that you're trying to implement ECIES without using a ECDH key agreement operation. I'd try using ECDH instead of coding the same using primitive operations.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @MaartenBodewes
Right now, I'm stuck. The problem is When I read encrypt.json when sending values through json format, I encode it after that. I read the value from the encrypt.json file that was sent and will decrypt but when decoding the hex value has changed. And I don't know what to do, I want to decipher by checking the value sent from encrypt.json. Can you be able to help me or coding example please ?

Comment: That'll easily cost me an hour, which is a bit too much. Try and use ECDH from a known good implementation, it should help you.